# How to print content between header and footer on every page using css?

Tags: html, css, printing

Content Should be displayed between header and footer on each print page regardless size(length) of the content.

In current code content overlap with header and footer. We need between header and footer.

Thank You!

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s8zU.png)

Sample Code:

```css
#main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
#title-company {
  background-color: #367fa9;
  padding: 5px;
}
.box-header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00c0ef;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  text-align: left;
}
@media print {
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #orderform {
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  #title-company {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #367fa9 !important;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  .sample-repeat {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 20pt;
  }
  .footer-content {
    bottom: 0pt;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main" class="sample-repeat">
    <div id="title-company"></div>
    <div class="box-header with-border" style="border-bottom: 3px solid #00c0ef;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">Header Section</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <address>
            <strong>Print Date & Time : </strong><span>12/08/2016 10:31:49</span><br>
          </address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <address>
            <strong>Del. Day & Time: </strong> <span>12/08/2016 10:31:49</span><br/>
          </address>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content</p>
    <p>Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content</p>
    <p>Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content</p>
    <p>Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content</p>
    <p>Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content Sample Page Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <span>Footer Content Print</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're tying to achieve?

Comment: can you please explain  where you stuck ?

Comment: I do not see them overlapping, do you mind elaborating on the problem ?

Comment: It's overlapping with header on every page. "Sample Page Content Sample Page" starts from the top on every page.

Comment: Attached "Output Screenshot". Please go through it.

Comment: i think your browser is outdated, Update your browser or use some modern browser.

Comment: @Muhammad and others: Take the time and take a look at it in the print preview - the error displayed in the screenshot happens in the newest Firefox and Chrome...

Comment: There is no any issue with the browser. I am using the latest version of Chrome and Firefox. There might be some issue with the css adjustment. Please go through it and if you found any solution for it, let us know. Any help will be appreciated.